# Gradle/Java Defining version in a single place

Tags: java, gradle

Sorry for the simplistic question, but I'm new to both Java and Gradle. I'm just looking for the simplest solution to do this.

So I created a class like:

```
public final class VERSION {
    public static final Integer majorVersion = 1;
    public static final Integer minorVersion = 0;
    public static final Integer patchVersion = 0;

    ...
}
```

While I'm new to Java, I've employed patterns similar to this with a variety of languages, and I'm happy with it.

The issue is that my project's build.gradle file also defines:

```
version "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

What's a simple way where I can define the version numbers in one place, so I stop forgetting to update them in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to define it in the build file or in the gradle.properties file.

Have a version.properties file in your project resources (src/main/resources);

```
version=@version@
```

, and configure the `processResources` task to filter this file in order to replace the version key(s) in this file:

```
def tokens = ['version': project.version]
processResources {
    filesMatching('version.properties') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: tokens)
    }
    inputs.properties(tokens);
}
```

Then, in your Java code, simply load the version from the `version.properties` resource:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties");
String version = props.getProperty("version");
```

Not tested, but you should get the idea.